ClickOnce получение аргументов командной строки WPF
Проект WPF .net 8.0. Публикую через ClickOnce на сетевой диск. Пытался всеми возможными способами вытащить аргументы.
у меня настроен IOC. Вот таким способом (код ниже) удаётся (!!!) получить аргументы лишь при отладке в студии.
public partial class App
{
    public static string[] Args;
}

[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var app = new App();
    App.Args = args;
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}

при запуске программы через cmd таким способом (цитата ниже) программа запускается без параметров.

C:>"%userprofile%\Desktop\ProgramName.appref-ms" arg1 arg2 arg3


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

(за ответ спасибо @EvgeniyZ)
Для получение аргументов командной строки конкретно для проекта WPF на NET 8, использующего ClickOnce, подойдёт следующий код:
string args = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_ActivationData_0");

Примечание. Если вы хотите указать несколько аргументов, то используйте знак-разделитель и соответствующе обработайте в коде участок получения аргументов.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/access-clickonce-activation-data-dotnet?view=vs-2022&source=recommendations

Полезно, спасибо!
